# Why cellInfo size is zero? It is zero when I get it with TelephonyManager

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I used cellInfo to get four parameters: rssi, rsrp, rsrq and sinr.
I can't find right solution to solve this problem.
Does anyone know how to get CellInfo?
I am currently using Android Emulator.
My Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
        for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
            if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                rssi = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getRssi();
                rsrp = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getRsrp();
                rsrq =  ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getRsrq();
                snr = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getRssnr();

            }
        }

    rssiValue.setText(String.valueOf(rssi));
    rsrpValue.setText(String.valueOf(rsrp));
    rsrqValue.setText(String.valueOf(rsrq));
    sinr.setText(String.valueOf(snr));
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same issue. I've added the FINE_LOCATION permission as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getAllCellInfo()) calling this method requires `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, you only ask for `COARSE`.